# callInWindow function was not executed

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I was working on a google tag custom template and there is one thing I'm quite confused about. When I try to use callInWindow, actually my global function wasn't executed.

For example, the function I want to call is `api.getUser().changeUserId(id)`, where api is my global function, and I wrote in my sandboxed javascript as `callInWindow('api.getUser.changeUserId', id)` but it didn't work. And when I try to use

```
const User = copyFromWindow("api.getUser"); 
User.changeUserId(id);
```

The firing status of my tag turned to 'Exception thrown'.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you given permissions to the `callInWindow` function? [CallInWindow in the docs.](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/api#callinwindow)

Comment: Also could you share the whole error message?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I give all the permissions to 'api', 'api.getUser' and 'api.getUser.changeUserId'. And could you please tell me how to check whole error message? I can only see 'Exception thrown' in the debug console of my demo page